# jquery hiding wrong submenu in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Im trying to create a mobile menu where if a menu item is clicked it slides down its sub menu. This is working but if the sub menu also has its own sub menu the first submenu is being hidden so you dont get to see its sub menu. I hope that makes sense.

Here's the code I have so far :

```js
// Mobile Menu Sub Menu Reveal
(function($) {
  "use strict";
  $('.mobile-menu li > .sub-menu').parent().on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
    if ($(submenu).is(':hidden')) {
      $(submenu).slideDown(200);
    } else {
      $(submenu).slideUp(200);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2a
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item 2c
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>item 2d</li>
            <li>item 2d</li>
            <li>item 2d</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to modify it so it works correctly ?

Ive created a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ukscotth/qon6j0b1/6/

Thanks.

Comment: Make a snippet to reproduce the error you have so we can help you better.

Comment: Add your html for your menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [stop the propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) so the click event doesn't bubble up to the parent li:

```js
// Mobile Menu Sub Menu Reveal
(function($) {
  "use strict";
  var $submenus = $('.sub-menu');
  var $submenuLiParents = $submenus.parent();

  $submenus.on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // this stops submenu closing when child links are clicked
  });

  $submenuLiParents.children('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // this prevents default action of links in li with a submenu
  });

  $submenuLiParents.on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // add this

    var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
    if (submenu.length) {
      if (submenu.is(':hidden')) {
        submenu.slideDown(200); // submenu is already a jquery object so you do not need to $(submenu)
      } else {
        submenu.slideUp(200);
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2a
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk">item 2c link won't work</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk">item 2d link will work</a></li>
            <li>item 2d</li>
            <li>item 2d</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. The only other issue i have is that the prevent default is stopping all the links from working, i just want to prevent the initial parent link, any ideas ?

Comment: take the link off the parent items?  Although if you keep the link, then you won't be able to open the submenus as it will just link to the page.  Usually when you have submenus the top menu item is not a link and then you have an item in the submenu that links to the parent item page

Comment: The problem is its for a wordpress theme and when the reviewer tests the theme they will want it to work with the demo data out of the box, without having to remove or change links etc

Comment: I don't get how you expect it to work then you want to open the submenu but still have the link to work?  If the link works, you will be redirected off the page and therefore the submenu will not open

Comment: I dont want the link to work on the submenu parent, want to disable it somehow without manually removing the link

Comment: See edit - just move the prevent default onto the direct child anchors of your li with submenus

Answer (score 0):

```
I have modified your code, please check this, in this code i have put the 
condition whether it have one level submenu or 2 level submenu and based on
that i have hide the menu

// Mobile Menu Sub Menu Reveal
(function($) {
    "use strict";
  $('.mobile-menu li > .sub-menu').parent().on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).find('.sub-menu').find('.sub-menu').length > 0){
        var submenu = $(this).find('.sub-menu').find('.sub-menu');
        if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
          $(submenu).slideDown(200);
        } else {
          $(submenu).slideUp(200);
        }
    }else{
        var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
        if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
          $(submenu).slideDown(200);
        } else {
          $(submenu).slideUp(200);
        }
    }

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks but now the initial sub menu wont open if itself has a submenu. Normal menu items with just one submenu seem to open fine.

Comment: can you please provide me your code or URL so that i can check with that and let you know

Comment: I have done some modification if you can see, please check https://jsfiddle.net/meet_pix/vmxn2etz/